# calling a restful WCF from Xamarin.Android application

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I am building an android application with VS 2012. When I make a webrequest for my WCF web service with this URL:

```
http://localhost:15763/Service1.svc/GetData
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
```

Comment: System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Comment: localhost is the Android device (or emulator) itself - you will need to host your service in IIS and reference it by a url or hostname, not localhost

Comment: it is already hosted by IIS but abiut the url reference : is there any specifications to make it or i could just choose a random url

Comment: it depends on how your WCF bindings are setup - but I would just try plugging in the IP of the server in place of localhost